# Is there a way to open links in the same tab as the periodical with Issuu?

Tags: flash, web, issuu

I'm afraid I might not be able to explain that question any more clearly. I click a link, it creates a new tab, this is not the desired functionality. Is there a way to ensure that links will open in the same tab?

Answer (score 0):

Yep you have to change the target parameter to "_self" instead of "_blank"

from the documentation :

> window:String (default = null) — The browser window or HTML frame in
>   which to display the document indicated by the request parameter. You
>   can enter the name of a specific window or use one of the following
>   values: "_self" specifies the current frame in the current window.
>   "_blank" specifies a new window. "_parent" specifies the parent of the
>   current frame. "_top" specifies the top-level frame in the current
>   window.

source : http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/package.html

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, that would require that I decompile each version of the embed that I"m using across all instances of my sites to add those changes, and would have to maintain it until the end of time so that I could ensure that it worked, as well as decompiling it not only for each individual pdf that is in the library that needs this feature but for each individual style as well. Seems like a lot of work for something so trivial.